# Delphi disable warnings fails

Tags: delphi, compiler-warnings

I have the following code in a Delphi 2007 application:

```
function TBaseCriteriaObject.RecursiveCount(
  ObjType: TBaseCriteriaObjectClass): integer;
var    
  CurObj: TBaseCriteriaObject;
begin
  result := 0;
{$WARNINGS OFF}
  for CurObj in RecursiveChildren(ObjType) do
    Inc(Result);
{$WARNINGS ON}
end;
```

Which produces this warning:

```
[DCC Warning] BaseCriteriaObject.pas(255): H2077 Value assigned to 'CurObj' never used
```

I understand the warning but don't want to change the code, so how do I get rid of the warning because {$WARNINGS OFF} does not seem to work in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Delphi Help:

> The $WARNINGS directive only works at
>   the procedure or function level
>   granularity. That is, you can surround
>   entire procedures and functions with
>   the $WARNINGS directive, but not
>   blocks of statements within a
>   procedure or function.

Comment: Cheers mate!  It also appears to be a hint, not a warning.  {$HINTS OFF} disables it (when around the procedure, not statement)

Comment: The warning setting used for a function is whatever setting was in effect at the point it reached the function's `end`.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: Interesting remark. You must have seen the compiler sources :).

Comment: Nah. Just been around the block before. The same rule applies to the overflow checking (`{$Q}`), but not range checking (`{$R}`).